# Strange behavior in align environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

I am getting this irregular behavior in horizontal alignment of some splitted equations over my document, this is only one example of it. The problem goes in the second `split` (which has practically the same structure than the first one). I have tried to correct it by putting `\\` here and there but with no success. I know that it could have a simple solution, but I can find it. What can I do? Is it a `bug` of `align` environment?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\di}{d\!}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sen}{\rm sen}

\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left\lvert\,\strut#1\,\right\rvert} %Absolute value


\begin{document}

\section{Trigonométricas Elementales}
\begin{align}
\int\sen x\,\di x & = -\cos x + C \\
\int\cos x\,\di x & = \sen x + C \\
    \begin{split}
        \int\tan x\,\di x   & = -\ln\abs{\cos x} + C \\
                            & = \ln \abs{\sec x} + C
    \end{split} \\
\int\csc x\,\di x & = -\ln\abs{\csc x- \cot x} + C \\
\int\sec x\,\di x & = -\ln\abs{\sec x+ \tan x} + C \\
    \begin{split}
        \int\cot x\,\di x & = \ln\abs{\cos x} + C \\
                          & = -\ln\abs{\csc x} + C \\
    \end{split} \\
\int\sen^2 x\,\di x & = \frac x2-\frac 14\sen 2x + C \\
\int\cos^2 x\,\di x & = \frac x2+\frac 14\sen 2x + C \\
\int\tan^2 x\,\di x & =\tan x - x + C
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I suggest `\newcommand{\di}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}` that frees you from typing `\,` before it and works more generally. Also, besides having been deprecated for 20+ years, `\rm` does nothing relevant in the definition of `\sen`.

Comment: Thank you @egreg. I will use your suggestion. As you pointed out, this can make me save some time and work. I did not know about `\rm`, I will take it into consideration in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Basically the same" is not the same as "the same"...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\di}{d\!}
\newcommand{\sen}{\mathop{\mathrm{sen}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left\lvert\,\strut#1\,\right\rvert} %Absolute value

\begin{document}

\section{Trigonométricas Elementales}
\begin{align}
  \int\sen x\,\di x & = -\cos x + C \\
  \int\cos x\,\di x & = \sen x + C \\
      \begin{split}
          \int\tan x\,\di x   & = -\ln\abs{\cos x} + C \\
                              & = \ln \abs{\sec x} + C
      \end{split} \\
  \int\csc x\,\di x & = -\ln\abs{\csc x- \cot x} + C \\
  \int\sec x\,\di x & = -\ln\abs{\sec x+ \tan x} + C \\
      \begin{split}
          \int\cot x\,\di x & = \ln\abs{\cos x} + C \\
                            & = -\ln\abs{\csc x} + C %\\ <---
      \end{split} \\
  \int\sen^2 x\,\di x & = \frac x2-\frac 14\sen 2x + C \\
  \int\cos^2 x\,\di x & = \frac x2+\frac 14\sen 2x + C \\
  \int\tan^2 x\,\di x & = \tan x - x + C
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I knew it! It has a ridiculously simple solution! I spent more time writting the question than you answering it! Thank you.

Comment: Optional but worthwhile: Provide a better `\abs` macro than the one provided by the OP. E.g., load the `mathtools` package and write `\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}`.

Comment: Excellent @Mico!. I will take that into consideration. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: @Mico I changed the command declaration as you suggested, but the new command does not work for "tall" equations like fractions or big operators with `\displaystyle`.

Comment: @Cragfelt - Please read the manual of the `mathtools` package for how `\abs` macro works. If you want auto-sized "fences", you need to type `\abs*{...}`.

Comment: Understood @Mico. I got it. Thank you for the details.