# How to create a two-columns tcbitemize?

Tags: pdftex, two-column, tcolorbox

Is it possible create a `tcbitemize` like this, but with two columns? If yes, how?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  margin=15mm,
  bindingoffset=2mm,
  heightrounded,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{listings,theorems}
\tcbuselibrary{raster}

\newtoggle{odditem}
\def\myitem{\iftoggle{odditem}%
{\color{black}\togglefalse{odditem}}%
{\color{blue}\toggletrue{odditem}}%
\olditem}

\newenvironment{myitemize}[1]{%
  \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]%
  \toggletrue{odditem}%
  \let\olditem\item%
  \let\item\myitem}{
  \end{itemize}
  }

\DeclareMathOperator{\eul}{e}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{|#1|}
\newcommand{\dint}[1]{\displaystyle \int #1 \;dx}
\newcommand{\fd}[1]{\dfrac{d}{dx} #1}
\definecolor{lime}{HTML}{32CD32}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=1,raster equal height,
colframe=red!83!black,colback=lime!5!white,fonttitle=\bfseries]
\tcbitem[squeezed title={DERIVATE}]
\begin{myitemize}{}
  \item $\fd{a} = 0$
  \item $\fd{x} = 1$
  \item $\fd{ax^{n}} = anx^{n-1}$
  \item $\fd{\eul^{x}} = \eul^{x}$
  \item $\fd{\ln (x)} = \dfrac{1}{x}$
  \item $\fd{\sin (x)} = \cos (x)$
  \item $\fd{\cos (x)} = -\sin (x)$
  \item $\fd{\tan (x)} = \dfrac{1}{\cos^{2} (x)}$
  \item $\fd{\cot (x)} = -\dfrac{1}{\sin^{2} (x)}$
  \item $\fd{\sec (x)} = \sec (x) \cdot \tan (x)$
  \item $\fd{\csc (x)} = -\csc (x) \cdot \cot (x)$
  \item $\fd{f[g(x)]} = f'(x)[g(x)] \cdot g'(x) $
  \item $\fd{f(x)\cdot g(x)} = f'(x) \cdot g(x) + f(x) \cdot g'(x)$
  \item $\fd{\left[\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right]} = \dfrac{f'(x) \cdot g(x) - f(x) \cdot g'(x)}{[g(x)]^{2}}$
  \item $\fd \arctan (x) = \dfrac{1}{1 + x^{2}}$
\end{myitemize}
\end{tcbitemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Without looking at anything: Have you tried `\begin{multicols}{2}` from the `multicols` package?

Comment: My idea was to use two columns, as in HTML, and be able to change the shape and color: multicols does all this?

Comment: Why don't you exploit the tcolorbox options and use the raster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a **Side by side tcolorbox**. Quoting documentation on page 116:

> A *side by side* box is a special tcolorbox where the upper and lower
>   part of the box are set side by side. All boxes of this kind are
>   unbreakable

Since there is no numbering in itemize, one can brake the *myitemize* environment and start it again in the lower part.

[image]

```
\begin{tcbitemize}[%
    raster columns=1,
    raster equal height,
    colframe=red!83!black,
    colback=lime!5!white,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    sidebyside]
\tcbitem[squeezed title={DERIVATE},sidebyside align=top]
\begin{myitemize}{}
  \item $\fd{a} = 0$
  \item $\fd{x} = 1$
  \item $\fd{ax^{n}} = anx^{n-1}$
  \item $\fd{\eul^{x}} = \eul^{x}$
  \item $\fd{\ln (x)} = \dfrac{1}{x}$
  \item $\fd{\sin (x)} = \cos (x)$
  \item $\fd{\cos (x)} = -\sin (x)$
  \item $\fd{\tan (x)} = \dfrac{1}{\cos^{2} (x)}$
\end{myitemize}
\tcblower
\begin{myitemize}{}
  \item $\fd{\cot (x)} = -\dfrac{1}{\sin^{2} (x)}$
  \item $\fd{\sec (x)} = \sec (x) \cdot \tan (x)$
  \item $\fd{\csc (x)} = -\csc (x) \cdot \cot (x)$
  \item $\fd{f[g(x)]} = f'(x)[g(x)] \cdot g'(x) $
  \item $\fd{f(x)\cdot g(x)} = f'(x) \cdot g(x) + f(x) \cdot g'(x)$
  \item $\fd{\left[\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right]} = \dfrac{f'(x) \cdot g(x) - f(x) \cdot g'(x)}{[g(x)]^{2}}$
  \item $\fd \arctan (x) = \dfrac{1}{1 + x^{2}}$
\end{myitemize}
\end{tcbitemize}
```

**UPDATE**

Alternatively, if you do not want the separating dashed line, you need to add the keys

```
colbacklower=lime!5!white,
bicolor,
```

in the tcolorbox configuration. So you will have

### [image]

**Off-topic**

A good practice in math symbol formatting is to define non-italic math operators in math-mode. There are some possible ways to achieve that, according to answer in [How can I define (user defined) functions in math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95171/how-can-i-define-user-defined-functions-in-math-mode/95174#95174), so I redefined **d** the math operator for differentiation with the line in preamble

```
\newcommand{\di}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
```

(which was suggested by @egreg in a comment in [my question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392638/strange-behavior-in-align-environment)), and making some changes in your custom command for differential derivative notation

```
\newcommand{\fd}[1]{\dfrac{\di}{\di x} #1}
```

the list of derivatives will look like this

[image]